# jvm class file encode utf8 but runtime in utf16, how to convert it

Tags: jvm

jvm class file encode utf8 but runtime in utf16, how to convert it

jvm class file encoded utf8, runtime string constant pool encoded utf16

I want to know where do convert

Comment: Class files don’t use UTF-8, they use *modified UTF-8*, however, there’s no need for you to convert anything, that’s what the JVM does for you.

Comment: Yeap, class files use modified utf-8, but runtime in string literal constant pool must be char array, which encoded utf-16. when class file loaded, jvm should convert from utf8 to utf16 when load string to constant pool

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: I got it, jvm internal convert utf8 to unicode when creating a string object